# What type of email address should I recreate to prevent this NDR?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

I deleted a user and need to recreate them.  What is the correct proxy address I need to setup to prevent these NDRs:

(sample)

> Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups:
>
> Camp, Erica
>   
>   The e-mail address you entered couldn't be found. Please check the
>   recipient's e-mail address and try to resend the message. If the
>   problem continues, please contact your helpdesk.

Answer (score 3):

I'm probably missing something obvious, but what is your goal?

- Do you want the mail intended for user *Erica Camp* to go somewhere? If so, you can forward mail sent to that mailbox to someone or add her address to an existing mailbox.
- Do you just want to disable non-delivery reports? If that's the case, they can be disabled in the Hub Transport.
- Are you trying to re-add the user? Is it a disconnected mailbox that needs to be reconnected? How recently was it disabled?
- Or was the AD user removed entirely and you're dealing with the after effects of someone's Outlook mail client cache?

If this is a cache issue, take a hint from this *lovely* error message.

> The email address you specified couldn't be found or is invalid. It
>   may be due to a bad entry in your Outlook or Outlook Web App recipient
>   AutoComplete cache. Use the steps below to clear the entry from the
>   cache: Click New mail. In the To field start typing the recipient's
>   name or email address until the recipient appears in the drop-down
>   list. Use the DOWN ARROW and UP ARROW keys to select the recipient,
>   and then press the DELETE key. Then resend your message – delete and
>   retype the recipient’s name or e-mail address before sending it.

Comment: my goal is to get those messages to a mailbox... since this is an address from an NK2 file, I'm not sure what it is...  (it's not SMTP)

Comment: @makerofthings7 Are you undeleting the user? Whose mailbox does it need to get to?

Comment: I'm disconnecting the mbx, moving it to a new/different AD account. In the process I didn't write down the prior email addresses.

Comment: Do you have access to the client sending the emails that generate the NDR?  If so, you should be able to use [NK2edit](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/outlook_nk2_edit.html) to extract the email address this client has cached.

Comment: @makerofthings7 And you don't know who the user was, and can't extrapolate their email address from previous messages, your email address policy or the message delivery logs?

Answer (score 2):

It depends, and it might not be possible.

The issue is often that Outlook clients will cache an "Exchange string" which references the actual mailbox associated with an email address.  And, much like you can't recreate a deleted AD object by making a new object with the same name (because the SIDs and GUIDs will be different), you can't recreate a deleted Exchange mailbox by making a new user with the same name and email addresses.

If this is the source of the issue, the only solution is to have the sending user delete the auto-complete entry.  If it's something else, well, Exchange NDRs are pretty horrible, so you'll probably have to use the message tracking features to hunt down the email that generated your NDR, and see which email addresses it sent to.